# How do I work on mvc form authentication to add custom fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I have created one web app using`mvc` and in that used`form authentication` for authenticate users.

i want to know if i want to `create new user` then there is a form which is having only limited field if i want to `add fields like contact , address etc.` then what i need to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the built-in asp.net membership providers whose defaults settings are such that they require a user to enter particular fields like username, password etc. to enter during registration. In your web.config, you can find this section :-

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

For the things, you are looking after, I would suggest you to first understand how this membership stuff works and then see how can you customize it accordingly.

You can start here :- [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)